# Actualizar y sumar fila en JTable en JAVA

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el codigo  `Add` logro hacer el calculo y agrego la fila pero con el metodo `Update` solo  logro actualizar la fila pero no hacer el calculo.

Que codigo podria agregar en el metodo `Update` para lograr lo que necesito...?

```
public class Add implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object[] row = new Object[4];
    row[0]= tx1.getText();
    row[1]= tx2.getText();
    row[2]= tx3.getText();  

    int  valor1,valor2,valor3,totales;

    valor1 =  Integer.parseInt(tx1.getText());
    valor2 = Integer.parseInt(tx2.getText());
    valor3 = Integer.parseInt(tx3.getText());

    totales = valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    row[3]=totales;

    model.addRow(row);
    sumarColumna();
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Update implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int i = tab1.getSelectedRow();
    if(i>=0){
      model.setValueAt(tx1.getText(), i, 0);
      model.setValueAt(tx2.getText(), i, 1);
      model.setValueAt(tx3.getText(), i, 2);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Seleccione la fila");
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya di con la solución gracias de antemano.

```
    int i = tab1.getSelectedRow();

    Object[] row = new Object[4];
    row[0]= tx1.getText();
    row[1]= tx2.getText();
    row[2]= tx3.getText();  


    int  valor1,valor2,valor3,totales;

    valor1 =  Integer.parseInt(tx1.getText());
    valor2 = Integer.parseInt(tx2.getText());
    valor3 = Integer.parseInt(tx3.getText());

    totales = valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    row[3]=totales;

    if(i>=0){
      model.setValueAt(valor1, i, 0);
      model.setValueAt(valor2, i, 1);
      model.setValueAt(valor3, i, 2);
      model.setValueAt(totales, i, 3);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Seleccione la fila");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada